# Whats wrong in this code to remove vowels?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def anti_vowel(t):
    v = "aeiouAEIOU"
    g = ""
    for i in t:
        for c in v:
            if i == c:
                g = g + i
    print(g)
anti_vowel("umbrella")
```

o/p : **uea**

Why am I getting the o/p with only vowels but i wanted to do the exact opposite?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
def anti_vowel(t):
    v = "aeiouAEIOU"
    r=[t]
    [r.append(r[-1].replace(l,'')) for l in v]
    return r[-1]
```

Comment: o/p - uuuuuuuuummmmmmmmmmbbbbbbbbbbrrrrrrrrrreeeeeeeeellllllllllllllllllllaaaaaaaaa

Comment: If i give the input as `anti_vowel(unmbrella)` ,The o/p i get is - uuuuuuuuummmmmmmmmmbbbbbbbbbbrrrrrrrrrreeeeeeeeellllllllllllllllllllaaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 2):

To make your code work, you can either switch to using `in`, or use a [`for-else`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) statement and `break` if you *do* have a vowel match:

```
def anti_vowel(t):
    v = "aeiouAEIOU"
    g = ""
    for i in t:
        for c in v:
            if i == c:
                break
        else:
            g += i
    return g
```

which does now give the intended output! :)

---

If you were after something slightly more efficient, you could use a generator with `str.join`:

```
def anti_vowel(t):
    v = "aeiouAEIOU"
    return ''.join(c for c in t if c not in v)
```

which we can see works:

```
>>> anti_vowel("umbrella")
'mbrll'
```

---

*Note that using `in` is faster than a `for-loop` as the operation is much more optimised at the `low-level`. It also produces much more readable (or Pythonic) code.*

---

*Oh and btw I believe functions should always have an output - even if the intention is to `print` that output, so I have used `returns` instead.*

Comment: if i change the `==` to `!=` i get the o/p- uuuuuuuuummmmmmmmmmbbbbbbbbbbrrrrrrrrrreeeeeeeeellllllllllllllllllllaaaaaaaaa